# Adding spreadsheet to google docs

Tags: c#, google-docs-api

I'm trying to add a new Spreadsheet to google docs. I'm using Visual Studio 2010, C#, .NET 4.0.

Here is my code:

```
       DocumentsService docService = new DocumentsService("Application-v1");
       DocumentEntry entry = new DocumentEntry();
       docService.setUserCredentials("my_email@gmail.com", "PASSWORD");
       entry.Title.Text = "AddingNewSpreadsheet";
       entry.Categories.Add(DocumentEntry.SPREADSHEET_CATEGORY);
       DocumentEntry newEntry = service.Insert(DocumentsListQuery.documentsBaseUri, entry);
```

When I run this code above, the Visual Studio returns me this error:

```
Execution of request failed: https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full
```

The error is shown in this line: 
`DocumentEntry newEntry = service.Insert(DocumentsListQuery.documentsBaseUri, entry);`

What I was supposed to use in my feed (first parameter of service.Insert())? Is the Documents.ListQuery.documentsBaseUri the right choice? How do I fix this error?